# PHP array. Checking values of 2 PHP arrays and combining the two

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a bit of a beginner to PHP and messing around with arrays a bit.

Is there any way to check the values of 2 arrays and combine the two (removing duplicates and such). I know this is unclear so I will provide an example:

```
$arrayOne = array("102", "103", "104", "105", "106");
$arrayTwo = array("101", "102", "103", "105", "106", "107");
```

Notice that $arrayOne does not have "101" and "107" and $arrayTwo does not have "104"

So what I want done is, combine the two arrays (into something like $array3). And when I run print_r($array3) I should get an output like:

```
Array([0] => 102, [1] => 103, [2] => 105, [3] => 106)
```

What has been done is: "101" and "107" has been removed from $arrayOne and "104" has been removed from $arrayTwo since these values were not common to both arrays. Additionally all duplicate values have been removed as well

Comment: try array intersect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_intersect`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_intersect.asp) did the work.

```
$arrayOne = array("102", "103", "104", "105", "106");
$arrayTwo = array("101", "102", "103", "105", "106", "107");

$result=array_intersect($arrayOne, $arrayTwo);
print_r($result); //Array ( [0] => 102 [1] => 103 [3] => 105 [4] => 106 )
```

If you need new index like you want than try `array_values`

```
print_r(array_values($result)); // Array ( [0] => 102 [1] => 103 [2] => 105 [3] => 106 )
```

Comment: That DOES work. Thanks a lot for the help and quick answer. Hope it was not a stupid question.. Still learning the ropes

Comment: I have to wait 11 minutes to accept your answer, apparently

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
$arrayOne = array("102", "103", "104", "105", "106");
$arrayTwo = array("101", "102", "103", "105", "106", "107");

$arrayThree = array();
foreach($arrayOne as $k => $v)
{
 if(in_array($v, $arrayTwo)){
   $arrayThree[] = $v;
 }
}

print_r($arrayThree);die;
```